# Chaining date/time in Razor

Tags: c#, razor

I'm working on a project that is meant to display a list of messages and the times/dates the messages are sent. 
The C# for setting the date is:

```
 public class Message
{
   public DateTime MessageSent { get; set; }
}
```

However this grabs both the date and time, but say if I wanted to display just the date I find myself doing this in the Razor:

```
<span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MessageSent.Day)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MessageSent.Month)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MessageSent.Year)</span>
```

But this seems really illogical. Is there a way I can chain day/month/year into just one statement? I know I can separate the date and time in the C# but is it possible do it just in Razor?

Comment: Just add a `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]` attribute on your property and it will render the correct format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below syntax

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MessageSent.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Comment: You can find the date format here. http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: perfect, thanks for the link too, thats very helpful!